# Can I run a command in background on server by exec_command of paramiko?

Tags: python, linux, ssh, paramiko

I use the `exec_command` of [Paramiko](http://www.lag.net/paramiko/) as following to run a **command in background** on server:

```
client.exec_command('test > /dev/null 2 > &1 &')
```

But I can't see the process by '`ps aux | grep test`'.

Why can this be?

Answer (score 1):

Because the "test" command exits with the status determined by the given expression.

The command is running in the background, but exiting right away.

Use another command and you'll see it running in the background.

Rob

Comment: for example use `sleep 100`. Also, check [nohup](http://ss64.com/bash/nohup.html).

Answer (score 0):

paramiko spawns a thread for each `.exec_command()` therefore you do not have to add the usual shell magic `&` as if you were in a bash. The `.exec_command()` will return instantly and you have to take care to read its buffers (stdin,stdout,sterr)

```
client.exec_command('test > /dev/null 2 > &1')
time.sleep(5)
client.exec_command('killall -9 test')
...
# the remot command will be force killed if you close the channel. (may depend on sshd implementation)
```

This will run `test` redirecting stderr to stdout in a spearate thread. the main thread is then going to sleep 5 seconds and another thread is spawned that kills test or if you do not kill it you just close the channel and the remote sshd will take care of all procs spawned during your session